# how to use json parsing in objective c class?

Tags: ios4

i got JSON formated data from my webservice and i want to parse that data and want to display that data into tableview so what i do , please help me , and if possible provide me full source code because i am new in iPhone developing and i started before 7 days, so please help me.

Thank YOu 
All in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

first download the TouchJSON Lib from fllowing link
https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON 
then add two require class to into your project where you want to parse JSON

```
- (NSString *)jsonFromURLString:(NSString *)urlString {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    [request release];

    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [resultString autorelease];

}
//////........this above class never change for any JSON webservice you need not to make change inti this class just add as it is.

#import "CJSONDeserializer.h"
-(void)JsonCall
{
    Array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *jsonURL = @"";////........your link gose here

    NSString *jsonString = [self jsonFromURLString:jsonURL];
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
    if([jsonData length]<=20)
    {

    }
    else{
        CJSONDeserializer *jsonDeserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *resultsArray = [jsonDeserializer deserialize:jsonData error:&error];
        for(int j =0; j<[resultsArray count]; j++)
        {
            NSDictionary *book = [resultsArray objectAtIndex:j];
            // Traverse through returned dictionary to populate tweets model
            //NSLog(@"");
            [Array addObject:book];
//////.........your data is in this array...........//////
        }


    }

}
```